# What are the neighborhoods of f(x)

Tags: general-topology

In general, does a neighborhood of a function g(x) have to contain only elements $y$ such that there exists an $x$ for which $f(x)=y$?

More concretely... I'm trying to learn topology from Munkres' book, and I've come across a really simple question that doesn't seem to be answered explicitly anywhere.
Working in the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$, define a function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} x \quad \text{if } x\in\mathbb{Q} \\ 0 \quad \text{if } x\not\in\mathbb{Q} \end{cases}$$

What exactly is a neighborhood of $f(x_0)$, if $x_0$ is rational? I know that in general the basis element for an open set on $\mathbb{R}$ is $(a,b)$, but is the set $U=(x_0-1,x_0+1)$ a neighborhood of $f(x_0)$? As in, does it matter that $f(x)$ never maps to any of the irrational values in $U$? The more I think about it the more I suspect that my original intuition was wrong and that it doesn't matter, but I'm not really sure.

**Note**: I'm using neighborhood as defined by Munkres: $U$ is a neighborhood of $x$ iff $U$ is an open set containing $x$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $(x_0 - 1, x_0 + 1)$ is a neighborhood of $f(x_0) = x_0$, when $x_0$ is rational.

This is because the open interval is open in the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$, and contains $f(x_0)$.

For $x_1 \notin \mathbb{Q}$ on the other hand, any open set containing $0$ is a neighborhood of $f(x_1)$ in this topology (and using your definition of neighborhood).

$g(x)$ is the value of the function $g$ at $x$. And no, the neighborhood of a point $g(x)$ does not need to only contain elements which are in the image of $g$. Just follow the definition.